# sql query in R, comparing two dates

Tags: sql, r

I have a DB with a column "date_time" which looks like 2020-08-11 18:06:37.
What I need now is to compare only the date with today's date.

e.g. 20200811 = 20200911

And I need it to compare it with the date 7 days before.

So I finally need this 20200811 = 20200911 - 7

I tried this, but it didn't work out.

```
abc <- paste("
              SELECT *
              FROM abcdef
              WHERE convert(dateime, abcdef.date_time, 114) = convert(datetime, ",Sys.Date(),",114)-7
             ")
```

Comment: Please tag your relational database as date/times are handled differently across dialects.

Comment: Should this be done in SQL or R?

Comment: I use an sql query in rstudio

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks like SQL Server.  You should do this in the database.

Assuming your date is really stored as a date/time and not as a string, I would recommend:

```
SELECT *
FROM abcdef
WHERE convert(date, abcdef.date_time) = dateadd(day, -7, convert(date, getdate()))
```